# How do I validate a spacy model at a nonstandard location?

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I'd like to check whether spaCy is compatible with the model that I installed to a nonstandard location. For example:

```
import spacy, os
nlp = spacy.load("../data/p1/p2/en_core_web_lg-3.2.0")
os.system("python -m spacy validate")
```

Problem: the above validates spacy with the model at the *standard* location; my model is at a nonstandard location: `../data/p1/p2/en_core_web_lg-3.2.0`

I'd like to do it in code. The command line
`python -m spacy validate`
does not take arguments. I'd like to do something like

```
assert(spacy.validate("../data/p1/p2/en_core_web_lg-3.2.0"))
```

before actually loading the model, but spacy has no function validate(). Or, is `spacy.load()` the only way to check for compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spacy validate` just checks model names against a list to tell you to update the official models if they're old, it doesn't actually do validation. It's for helping with the upgrade from v2 to v3, and to help the dev team when troubleshooting user reports.

If you have a custom model, you should just use `spacy.load` to check your model.

It seems like you installed a non-custom model to a non-standard location. If you `pip install` it you can check it with `spacy validate`, but otherwise it won't check it.

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking for a way to check before loading, I guess there's no reason to do so.